# Play array of videos in html5

Tags: html, html5-video

I've looked at web sources to find out how to play an array of videos in html5. Using the sources, I have only managed to get the first video to show up (no autoplay) and even when I clicked "play" button  manually, the second video does not auto-play/show up after the first one ended. Any idea?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Video.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.Video.VideoDashboard" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls="controls" id="myVideo">
    </video>
     <script>
            var videoSource = new Array();
            videoSource[0] = "/MP4Files/Video1.mp4";
            videoSource[1] = "/MP4Files/Video2.mp4";
            var i = 0; // define i
            var videoCount = videoSource.length;

            function videoPlay(videoNum) {
                document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
                document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
                document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
            }
            document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
            videoPlay(i); // play the video

            function myHandler() {
                i++;
                if (i == (videoCount - 1)) {
                    i = 0;
                    videoPlay(i);
                } else {
                    videoPlay(i);
                }
            }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are selecting the same element with ID "myVideo". Add a number to your videos' element. For example "myVideo-1". And then use the variable "videoNum" like this document.getElementById("myVideo-1") , document.getElementById("myVideo-2") ...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ryanc. I managed to get the 2nd video to play after the first by changing the IF logic in the myHandler function. However, i'm currently only able to autoplay the video when I add the muted attribute to the video tag.